# Running Spring DMLC as CRON

Tags: spring, jms, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to Spring DMLC (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) to consume messages (say every 10 minutes) using CRON?

I don't want the messages to be picked up by Spring DMLC all the times.

Let's say a message is produced and dropped off into the JMS broker, I like the consumer (Spring DMLC) to pick up after some time for processing.

I am wondering if there is a way to configure Spring DMLC and Quartz?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a DMLC in that case? If you use spring, a [JMSTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) might be what you are looking for.

```
void readOneMessageAndProcess() throws JmsException{
   Message msg = jmsTemplate.receive("SOME.QUEUE");
   // Process.
}
```

Then have Quartz, java timer, or a simple `public static void main(String args[])` triggerd by a cron job run the method